# Decreasing success chance with each trial

Tags: probability

Starting at level 0, you spend tokens to attempt to increase your level by 1 (maximum level 6).

Failures reset your level to 0, and all tokens spent are lost.

I'm trying to figure out the average number of tokens spent upon getting 6 successes in a row.

| Level | Tokens | p |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 100% |
| 1 | 1 | 50% |
| 2 | 2 | 50% |
| 3 | 2 | 40% |
| 4 | 3 | 30% |
| 5 | 3 | 26% |

My initial calculation was to take the average number of attempts needed  (1/[compounded p]) for each level to create the number of attempts and multiply that by the cumulative sum of tokens spent.

| Level | Tokens | Σ(Tokens) | p | Compounded(p) | Attempts | Spent Tokens |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 100% | 100% | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 50% | 50% | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 50% | 25% | 4 | 16 |
| 3 | 2 | 6 | 40% | 10% | 10 | 60 |
| 4 | 3 | 9 | 30% | 3% | 34 | 300 |
| 5 | 3 | 12 | 26% | .78% | 129 | 1539 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | **1920** |

So the average number of tokens needed would be 1920. Is this correct?

Comment: It looks like you're counting each token spent at every level before level 5 more than once. Also, it isn't the case that the expected tokens spent to get to a certain level is equal to the minimum total number of tokens divided by the compounded probability, because some of the failures will likely spend fewer tokens.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not - the correct number is approximately 384. I ellaborate as to how I got that result (and why the proposed approach could have failed) below.**

*How to compute the number of tokens spent?*

Define $X_i$ for $0\leq i \leq 5$ as the number of tokens needed before attaining $6$ successes in a row, if we already have had $i$ successes. Then, what we wish to calculate is $\mathbb{E}[X_0]$.

We can express the expectations of these random variables in terms of each other by conditioning to the outcome of the next attempt. In more detail, for each $i$ we have that:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mathbb{P}(\{\text{Failure at level }i\})(\mathbb{E}[X_0] + T_i) + \mathbb{P}(\{\text{Success at level }i\})(\mathbb{E}[X_{i+1}] + T_i),
$$
where $T_i$ are the number of tokens spent in an attempt from level $i$ and $X_6=0$. More concretely:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_0] = 1 \cdot (\mathbb{E}[X_1]+1), \\
\mathbb{E}[X_1] = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbb{E}[X_0]+1) + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbb{E}[X_2]+1), \\
\mathbb{E}[X_2] = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbb{E}[X_0]+2) + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbb{E}[X_3]+2), \\
\mathbb{E}[X_3] = \frac{3}{5}(\mathbb{E}[X_0]+2) + \frac{2}{5}(\mathbb{E}[X_4]+2), \\
\mathbb{E}[X_4] = \frac{7}{10}(\mathbb{E}[X_0]+3) + \frac{3}{10}(\mathbb{E}[X_5]+3), \\
\mathbb{E}[X_5] = \frac{37}{50}(\mathbb{E}[X_0]+3) + \frac{13}{50}(\mathbb{E}[X_6]+3).
$$

Now, we can find the expectation by solving this linear system of equations, treating $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ as variables for each $0\leq i \leq 5$. This got me approximately 384 tokens spent in expectation. You can verify the calculations [here](https://matrixcalc.org/es/#%7B%7B1,-1,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B-0%2E5,1,-0%2E5,0,0,0%7D,%7B-0%2E5,0,1,-0%2E5,0,0%7D,%7B-0%2E6,0,0,1,-0%2E4,0%7D,%7B-0%2E7,0,0,0,1,-0%2E3%7D,%7B-0%2E74,0,0,0,0,1%7D%7D%5E%28-1%29*%7B%7B1%7D,%7B1%7D,%7B2%7D,%7B2%7D,%7B3%7D,%7B3%7D%7D).

*Why the proposed approach fails?*

A reason why could be that, as the recursion shows, we need to carefully keep track of how many tokens we spend in between failures, which depends on the level at which we failed. Just compounding the probability will not work because it maters where we fail in the middle of our attempts, and compounding just tests whether we failed or not. Please feel free to comment if you see another reason or have another intuition!